# 4-Torsion on an elliptic curve embedded in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ as the intersection of two quadrics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I'm having trouble with exercise 3.10 from Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*. I include part (a) for context and part (d) because that's the part I'm stuck on. All fields in this section are algebraically closed.

> Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve with Weierstrass coordinate functions $x$ and $y$.
>
> (a) Show that the map 
>   $$
> \phi: E \to \mathbb{P}^{3} 
> $$
>   defined by
>   $$
> \phi = [1 : x : y : x^{2}]
> $$
>   maps $E$ isomorphically onto the image of two quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$.
>
> (d) Let $P \in E$. Prove that $[4]P = \mathcal{O}$ if and only if there exists a hyperplane $H \subset \mathbb{P}^{3}$ such that $\phi(E) \cap H = \{ P \}$. If char($K$) $\neq 2$, prove that there are exactly $16$ such hyperplanes, and hence that $\#E[4] = 16$.

I assume char$K$ $\neq 2, 3$ for notational convenience. Thus $E/K$ is isomorphic to a plane curve given by equation 
$$
y^{2} = x^{3} + ax + b
$$
where $4a^{3} - 27b^{2} \neq 0$. The quadrics described in part (a) should then be given by
$$
Q_{1}: z_{1} = z_{3}z_{0}
$$
$$
Q_{2}: z_{2}^{2} = z_{3}z_{1} + az_{1}z_{0} + bz_{0}^{2}
$$
where the $z_{i}$ are homogeneous coordinates on $\mathbb{P}^{3}$.
The first part of (d) follows immediately from part (c). I'm having trouble with the hyperplanes, here is my latest attempt:
We first note that there are $4$ immediate $4$-torsion points of $E$ given by $\mathcal{O}$ and the $3$ points of order $2$ corresponding to the roots of the equation $x^{3} + ax + b$. This gives us $4$ hyperplanes with the required intersection property. It can be checked that $[0 : 0 : 0 : 1] = \phi(\mathcal{O})$  and that this is the only point on both quadrics where $z_{0} = 0$, so we can assume $z_{0} \neq 0$. We can also assume $z_{2} \neq 0$ since these points are the images of the points of order $2$.

Now consider a general hyperplane:
$$
H: c_{0}z_{0} + c_{1}z_{1} + c_{2}z_{2} + c_{3}z_{3}.
$$
If $c_{3} = 0$ then $H$ passes through $\phi(\mathcal{O})$ and so if it intersects $\phi(E)$ once could only be one of the hyperplanes we have already counted, so we can assume $c_{3} \neq 0$ and since the hyperlanes are parameterised by $\mathbb{P}^{3}$, we can assume $c_{3} = 1$ . Thus setting $u = \frac{z_{1}}{z_{0}}$, $v = \frac{z_{2}}{z_{0}}$, $w = \frac{z_{3}}{z_{0}}$, we reduce to
$$
Q_{1}: u^{2} = w
$$
$$
Q_{2}: v^{2} = wu + au + b
$$
$$
H: c_{0} + c_{1}u + c_{2}v + w = 0.
$$
The first equation clearly makes $w$ redundant so we can reduce to two equations:
$$
Q: v^{2} = u^{3} + au + b
$$
$$
H: c_{0} + c_{1}u + c_{2}v + u^{2} = 0
$$
so finally I've reduced to the intersection of an elliptic curve and a quadratic. When we do the necessary substitutions we get a quartic in $u$, which we would need to have a repeated root. I've attempted various ways using the coefficients to obtain equations in the $c_{i}$  ( formally differentiating multiple times to obtain the root and then comparing coefficients with binomial expansion etc) but each has left me with a confusing mess, so I can't help thinking I've gone wrong somewhere above. Also I never used the $z_{2} \neq 2$ condition. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: The purpose of this question is to prove in the special case $m = 4$ that deg$[m] = m^{2}$, so ideally I'd like answers that don't quote this result.

Answer (score 1):

For part (d) just note that any two hyperplane sections of the curve are linearly equivalent. In particualar, if $H$ and $H'$ are such that $\phi(E) \cap H = 4P$ and $\phi(E) \cap H' = 4P'$ then $4P \sim 4P'$. Since there is a hyperplane $H_0$ (given by $z_0 = 0$) such that $\phi(E) = 4P_0$, where $P_0$ is the origin of the curve, it follows that any for any $H$ as above $4P \sim 4P_0$.

Conversely, if $4p \sim 4P_0$ then there is a hyperplane $H$ such that $\phi(E) \cap H = 4P$ just because any divisor linearly equivalent to $4P_0$ is a hyperplane section of $E$ (since $\phi$ is given by a COMPLETE linear system).

Comment: Thanks for the response, how would you go about showing that there are precisely 16 hyperplanes that intersect at exactly one point?

Comment: Just because each 4-torsion point creates such a hyperplane.

Comment: and how do you know there are 16 4-torsion points? (I think the general thrust of this question is towards proving that deg[4] = 16 rather than quoting it, in which case the result does indeed follow trivially).

Comment: @RobRockwood Did you end up sorting this question out? I'm working through the same exercise now and had essentially the same question as you about getting the number 16.